# Connecting every other DIN terminal to each other

Tags: ground, control, control-system, plc, din

I am building a custom panel. My output DIN terminals are supposed to be in this order: Power, Ground, Power, Ground, Power, Ground.... I cannot find a proper way (jumpers or bars) to connect them. Only solution I can come up with is using jumper wires which is very sketchy. What is a good practice to connect such terminals together?
(I decided not to use the rails as ground as they are connected to Earth ground and I have multiple isolated circuits, got multiple solenoid loaded circuits.)

Thank you!

Update: I found these bridges on Amazon:
[image]

Turns out you can remove any screw you want, so I created my custom order jumper. Since I needed multiple of these, I connected them together using ring terminals, and it worked like a charm. Thank you to everyone who helped!

Comment: DIN? several of their standards describe electrical connections, which one are you using?

Comment: DIN 35 rail terminals, here is an example: https://www.amazon.ca/Dinkle-Assembly-Connector-Terminal-Separate/dp/B01HSJFJX8/ref=sr_1_5?crid=1HDHKCREKX978&keywords=din+terminal&qid=1702436461&sprefix=din+terminal%2Caps%2C95&sr=8-5

Comment: These are DIN-rail-mount terminal blocks. Just use wires.

Comment: I was thinking a "comb busbar" could do that, but finding one with the right pitch to fit feed-through connectors is much harder than finding one for breakers.

Comment: @Hearth that is my back-up plan. That introduces a lot of SPFM. I'm trying to see if experienced engineers can tell me if there is a neater way of doing it.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні thanks! The only issue is it is very difficult to cut those cleanly. I found a tool (outlined in this video for other people: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJl9zhSGVVE&t=55s) and might get it. Honestly, I might just get a machine shop to custom make a shorting terminal for me.

Comment: I found  Weidmüller 1579000000
but you'd have to buy two and chop half of the pins of each and then insulate the cuts... :(
as you suggest drawing a picture and sending it to to someone with a water jet cutter is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні I really appreciate it! I think that's what I need to do, and think better for my next panel. I quickly designed a rod and getting that done in a shop might be cheaper. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have discovered, DIN terminals that can accomodate alternating jumper components are hard to find - if they exist at all. This is in contrast to DIN rail mounting MCBs which are available with three-phase jumper bars.

[image]

*Figure 1. Wago double-deck cage-clamp terminal. Image source: [Wago](https://www.wago.com/us/rail-chassis-terminal-blocks/double-deck-terminal-block/p/870-501).*

The double-deck terminals supplied by many companies provide a neat solution to the problem. Jumper bars can be inserted in the positions marked by the red arrows. The double (or triple) deck solution means that all the neutrals can be on the lower deck and all the live wires on the upper deck. As a bonus you get a double-density solution.

[image]

*Figure 2. Triple-deck terminals (left) on a panel before installation. External wiring will be terminated in the bottom of the terminals. Image source: [Design World Online](https://www.designworldonline.com/basics-of-terminal-blocks-and-their-various-subtypes/).*

Comment: Thanks, I also thought about these but the ones on McMaster-Carr were quite expensive. This is the neatest solution in my opinion and will look more into them in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use a twin-wire ferrule and daisy-chain the wires down the line of terminal blocks. Don't forget that the wire will need to be rated for the current draw of the sum total of all the terminal blocks. Also don't forget to use a proper crimper and torque driver on the terminal connections.

Answer (score 1):

Turn "Power, Ground, Power, Ground, Power, Ground" into "Power, Power, Power, Ground, Ground, Ground" and use distribution blocks or jumpers.

Or, use terminals with two levels. Where you can jump each level.

If you must use these specific terminals, wires are your only option.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a job for a custom board with the matching DIN plug (you might want to specify that, more than one connector has been called "DIN connector").

Comment: No, this question is about these: https://www.motioncontroltips.com/whats-there-to-know-about-terminal-blocks-for-control-applications/

Comment: I'm looking for DIN terminal blocks, not connectors.